# What happens if an error occurs during a Rails Pessimistic Lock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, locking

[Pessimistic Lock](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/locking/pessimistic.rb) creates a transaction. What happens if there is an error during the transaction and it does not complete?

Using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction is aborted and the lock is released.  Since the transaction is aborted, no updates made in the transaction prior to the exception are committed.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html